# Marshaling incorrect integer value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop a program to parse any string as given fixed character length.

Instead of writing my own parser class, I decided use marshaling. As below I defined a structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public string Name;              

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int Age;              

}
```

I call this struct like this;

```
string message = "SampleName30";
IntPtr pBuf = Marshal.StringToBSTR(message);
MyStruct ms = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pBuf, typeof(MyStruct));
```

If I check the value:

```
ms.Name is SampleName // OK
```

But `ms.Age` value returns `3145779`. I expect `ms.Age = 30`

What is the wrong?  How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Using marshaling here seems like a pretty bad idea...

Comment: It shouldn't be used for UnamangedType.I4 but why are you using SizeConst? It's not an array or a string. Can you post the unmanaged structure definition?

Comment: My purpose is setting the last 2 character as age. So i give sizeconst on structure.

Comment: Hi Daniel , why don't you prefer marshal?

Answer (score 2):

It's a very big mess you've made.

First thing's first. 3145779 is 300033 in hexadecimal. '3' is 33 in hex, '0' is 30 in hex, add some unicode and endianess and you get to 300033 (I didn't reproduce this exactly, because it doesn't really matter here).

You *can't* convert a string to a number this way, you need to decode it - translate each digit character to its numerical value.

Why are you trying to parse your string this way? Isn't it eons better to use this code:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;

    public static MyStruct ParseString(string s)
    {
        var my = new MyStruct();

        Name = s.substring(0, 10);
        Age = int.Parse(s.substring(11))
    }
}
```

You should make the interface a bit tidier (properties? a constructor instead of a Parse method?), and take care of errors (shorter or longer strings, invalid integers), but that's the jist.

Comment: I'm working on my accept-rate - number of answers accepted :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you have a string `"30"` and not an integer `30`. The binary representation of the unicode string `"30"` is the same as the binary representation of the number `3145779`.

I suggest you build your own parser, that's not the task to use marshaling for.

Comment: I have too much struct. So this way seems very easy. I write string length just one on the struct attribute. And marshal automaticly parse it given length.
I can get the "Age" as string but i want to check value Numeric or not. Get these info enough for me.

Could i get the value is Numeric or else send an Exception?